# Cycles play pause button is missing cant render viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

it looks like my play pause button is gone so i cant use the render preview view port because its stuck on off. please help! it was there before but now i cant get it back to tell the view port to render

[image: missing play pause button]

[image: Play pause button that im looking for]

Comment: Hello :). Just to make sure - isn't the viewport window too narrow? That would hide some controls.

Comment: thanks but the window definitely isnt too small